# Event driven train simulation, can't seem to wrap my head around it

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, containers, simulation

I've been working on this project for a really long time and I'm sad to say that I'll soon give up on it, simply because I can't wrap my head around it.. Every time I try and write a UML or the code I get stuck, I've been stuck for almost eight weeks. So as a last resort I'm turning to SO for some help. And I know I should provide a more complete solution for you guys to help me with but since I haven't gotten any further than what I'm about to show futher down in this question there is not much to show.

Any way..
The task is to create an event driven train simulation. 
I'll list the requirements first.

### The requirements are:

#### Vehicle

- All vehicles has a unique ID number.
- One important feature is a virtual function that can provide a string representation of detailed information about a given vehicle.
- The different types of vehicles and their properties are:

  > 1. Locomotives
  >
  >    - A diesel locomotive  [*Maximum speed and fuel consumption*]
  >    - A electric locomotive  [*Maximum speed and effect*]
  > 2. Passenger Car
  >
  >    - Sitting Car  [*Amount of seats and Wifi Yes/No*]
  >    - Sleep Car  [*Amount of beds*]
  > 3. Goods Car
  >
  >    - Open Goods Car  [*Loading capacity and loading space*]
  >    - Closed Goods Car  [*Capacity*]
- When it comes to the vehicles we can state that a given vehicle is either in a stations vehicle pool or in a train. But no vehicle objects should be moved around. All objects are created dynamically at startup (vehicle data is read from some file) and during the simulation you just transfer the ownership of a vehicle by means of shuffle the pointers around.

#### Train

- Every train, or rather train connection, from one town to another has a unique train ID.

  > This ID is a logical ID and a train with a given ID runs everyday from the same departure town to the same destination at the the same time with the same PRINCIPAL composition. I.e. a train with a given ID always has the same set of vehicles when it comes to vehicle types and numbers but not when it comes to actual vehicles.
- The trains consists of different types of Vehicles. A train can also consist of the same type of vehicles, eg. Train number 859 consists of two electric locomotives and three sleep cars.
- A train is assembled on the trains departure station.

  > The vehicles differs from day to day depending on the available vehicles at the departure station. 
  >   If the train cannot be assembled it is delayed until it can be assembled.
- Each train goes through six different states.

  > NOT ASSEMBLED - the train exists, but only as a logical concept, no locomotives/cars are connected. 
  >   NOT READY - the train is being assembled at it current station, cars are getting connected. 
  >   READY - the train is now ready to departure from its station. 
  >   RUNNING - its on the move and going towards its destination. 
  >   ARRIVED - the train has now reached it destination. 
  >   FINISHED - the train is being detached and the vehicles now goes to the Stations vehicle pool and the vehicles can now be used for other trains on the station.

#### Station

- Every station has a pool of available vehicles, as a hint we are given that a station has a container for vehicle pointers as a data member.
- If a train can't be assembled at station, because the stations vehicle pool doesn't have the needed vehicles for a train, it will be delayed and the train will still remain in the "NOT ASSEMBLED"-state.

#### Simulation

- In short the simulation should take place from one point in time to another, say from 08.00 to 16.00. During the simulation the user can always access information about any given vehicle in the simulation, any train or train station in the simulation. At the start of the simulation a maximum of three files are read and in those three files all information about vehicles/trains/stations is stored.
- The start information from the files cannot contain vehicle IDs for the train, only their types (eg. "DIESEL_LOCOMOTIVE"). The exact vehicle ID is established once the train is being Assembled (moving from the "NOT READY" state to "READY" state)
- The user steps through the simulation with 10 minute long steps and the simulation updates all the states/positions/pools etc. accordingly.

I know that a classic approach is to scan the description to find nouns that might be classes and verbs that might be operations. A quick walk-through gives some central classes: Vehicle, Train, Station, Connection, TimeTable etc. But I'm at a complete halt with this assignment. I'm getting nothing done and starting to loose it. I've written so many UML-diagrams to help me guide the coding, and I've written so many programs with different types implementations that I'm at the verge of giving up. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sometimes it's helpful to temporarily turn everything upside down - throw some code together which does at least some of the task, get it working more or less, and in the process you should get some insight as to what the high level design should look like. Then go back to your UML with this fresh insight.

Comment: @PaulR, thanks for the advice. And I have tried that, multiple times, with little to no luck. I've done so many implementations of the Station-class and the Train-class. And almost every time I get stuck on the same part, the part where the train and the station should collaborate. Firstly the station must check its vehicle pool, then the station must check what types of vehicles the train is demanding to be able to run to the next station. I can't really see how I should implement that feature where the train "knows" it composition..

Comment: I think you can't see the wood for the trees and that you are trying to bite off more than you can chew.  Search the Internet for resources on *discrete event simulation* and learn how some people have tackled this type of problem before.  Next, start simple: try getting one train running from one station to another. Ensure that your system reports the data you want from the simulation.  Now start adding complexity, perhaps have 2 trains sharing a track and program collision avoidance.  Finally, this question is too broad for good answers within SO's rather strict rules, so I'm voting to close

Comment: If you want to have an event-based simulation, you need to embrace the discrete-event modeling paradigm.  Please check out http://www.informs-sim.org/wsc06papers/001.pdf for a tutorial.  I agree with @HighPerformanceMark that starting smaller and building up is a good idea.

Comment: And another thing, just to make your forest deeper and more tangled.  Your analysis omits any mention of either the tracks along which the trains will run or the signals which control train movements.  Go back to basics.

Comment: Note that "system steps in 10 min increments" is not DES. DES, as the name suggests, is based on events to move time forward. So one entity will emit an event that signifies that a certain change will occur in 10 minutes (like train arrival), and another entity will emit an event that signifies that something will happen in 8 minutes. The event queue will have two events, and the time will jump ahead 8 minutes, then 2 minutes (unless what happened at 8 minutes caused a new event to occur at the 1 minute). It's a very different way of thinking about a system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is closer to system requirements than user requirements. This can be problematic as the former is how you solve the problem, the latter is the problem you are trying to solve. If that is not clear, your solution will be erratic. For example,

> If a train can't be assembled at station, because the stations vehicle
>   pool doesn't have the needed vehicles for a train, it will be delayed
>   and the train will still remain in the "NOT ASSEMBLED"-state.

This is a system requirement. What user requirement resulted in having to assemble a train at a station, what does the user need to do that requires this?

My guess is that you are jumping too quickly into the complexities of the problem. Clearly define a couple simple objectives and detail them with some user requirements, and keep it simple. If you have 6 types of vehicles and 6 states etc and no clear top level user requirements, you are over thinking and going too fast. Once you have a simple set of user requirements, and you architect a solution that is DES based, you can take a quick step back and think how you should modify it so you can later incorporate more complexity without having to redo a pile of stuff but this may be premature. Iterations is best approach, learn the problem domain (something about trains but what specifically I'm not sure), and learn the solution technique (DES) gradually.

I agree with comments that this is too broad for SO but I hope the above helps, good luck.